# How to Analyze the Running Time of a Python For-Loop?

Tags: python, performance, complexity-theory

Consider the following line-by-line analysis of a classical for-loop:

```
1 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {    | 1 + N + (N - 1)
2                                  |
3     //do something               | c
4                                  |
5 }                                |
```

In this example, the initialization of the for-loop takes one primitive operation, the loop condition is checked `N` times and the variable `i` is incremented `N - 1` times while the body of the loop takes `c` primite operations, for some constant `c`. This means that line `1` is executed `1 + N + (N - 1)` times, while the body of the loop is executed `N` times. However, in Python this analysis wouldn't work because for-loops in Python are implemented by using iterators. Consider the following simple example:

```
1 for i in range(len(N)):          | ?
2     //do something               | c
```

If I would like to analyze the running time of this code snippet line-by-line as I already did above, how would I do that? Should I assume that line 1 is executed `N` times like in a classical for-loop or does it make more sense to say that in Python line 1 is executed one time and only the body of the loop is executed `N` times?

Answer (score 1):

`range()` gives you an iterator. Fetching the next value from the iterator is an `O(1)` operation. The for loop merely fetches the next value from the iterator `N` times which makes it `N * O(1)` or `O(N)`. The loop exits when the iterator raises a `StopIteration` which is handled by the for-loop to exit the loop. This is also `O(1)`.

The high-level operations in python can't exactly be counted like the one in C.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you trying to calculate asymptotics, but you dont understand how it works :(

You cant say, that the classical for-loop (e.g. c++) executes `T(C * (1 + N + (N - 1))`, because all depends from 1000 and 1 other things, e.g. compiler...

If u want to calculate asymptotics (in our days) — better use O-notation, which says that both codes execute with `O(C * N)` operations.